# How to fake writes to certain folders

Tags: linux, mount, docker

I'm building Docker containers using an executable installer that is not very configurable.  It wants to install about 9GB of modules in various folders around the system, of which I actually need to keep about 500MB.  Instead of waiting for the installer to write to all of these files, then deleting the ones I don't need, it would be nice to be able to fake writes to these directories, where instead of actually doing disk I/O, these writes just disappear into the ether.

Is there a way to set up a folder that will not persist any files written to it and doesn't require waiting for disk I/O when writing?

Comment: why not just build one container that's gone through the full install 9GB and prune to 500MB procedure, and then use that as the base for the other containers?